# Corresponding between prime ideals in $C(X)$ and $C^*(X)$

Tags: gn.general-topology

we know that every maximal ideal in $C(X)$ is in this form:

$$M^p=\left\{\,f \in C^*(x):\  p\in cl_{\beta X} Z\left(f\right)\,\right\}$$

and every maximal ideal in $C^*(X)$ is

$$M^{*p}=\left\{\,f\in C^*(X):\  f^{\beta}\left(p\right)=0\,\right\}$$

and it is not necessary that

$$ M^p \cap C^*(X) = M^{*p}$$

My question is:

### If are prime ideals of $C(X)$ contained in $M^p$, in a one to one corresponding to that of $C^*(X)$ contained in $M^{*p}$ for $p\in \beta X$ ?

$M^p$ and $M^{*p}$ are maximal ideals respectively in $C(X)$ and $C^*(X)$ correspond to $p$.
$\beta X$ is Ston-cech compactification of the space $X$
for terminology and notions you can refer to [here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=3j3SBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=Rings+of+continuous+functions&ots=0UmBXt62ta&sig=yhl_h8zAq9FKOJBIxZ1-1UgEyTc#).

### Edite

you can find $\beta X$ at the beginning of Ch.6 and if you want more you should continue. also in Ch.7 section 7.11, it deal whit corresponding between maximal ideals specially.

Comment: If you want people to help you out by doing some work to solve your problem, you're going to have to explain your notation better. I clicked your link but I'm not going to hunt through an entire book to find definitions of notation that you could easily supply in your question.

Comment: Why do you use 'continued-fractions' tag?

Comment: sorry dears.l am grateful to you for your considerations.

Comment: But I think, this is better to deal whit my question in a more specialized page.

Comment: Is there such page for C(X) here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the prime ideals of $C(X)$ and $C^*(X)$ is not in a one to one corresponding. In fact, The prime ideals of $C(X)$ contained in $M^p$ is in one to one corresponding with that of $C^*(X)$ contained in $M^{*p}$ if and only if $p\in \upsilon X$, where $\upsilon X$ is the Hewitt-Nachbin space (real compactification of X).
For more information one can see [here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=3j3SBwAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=gillman%202013%20rings&ots=0UnyQB6_y6&sig=UrMNqsHnz26MgSufm8Ug-s7F-4Y)
Chapter 8 specially p. 119, Problem 7. J and Problem 7. K.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the correspondence $M^p \mapsto M^{*p}$ (and vice versa) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks dear.No I don't.I 'm looking for the correspondence $P\rightarrow P\cap C^*(X)$.